# Access is denied 0x80070005 in windows phone 8.1 when I open stream to write with taglib sharp portable

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, access-denied, taglib-sharp, storagefile

there.
I have a little problem with taglib sharp portable.
I want to open a stream from music library and I want to rewrite properties of a file.

My code is:

```
StorageFolder musicFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
StorageFile file = await musicFolder.GetFileAsync( filename );
var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
File tags = File.Create( new StreamFileAbstraction( filename, stream, stream ) );

.... // modify my tags

tags.Save();
```

In `var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()`, I have this error:

> 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll Access is
>   denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

What's the problem?
This code works if I want to open a stream for read only the tags.
Why this code not works?
If I use taglib sharp (not portable) and I do:

```
File tags = File.Create( filepath );
```

I have a problem in `tags.Save()` with a error

> System.StackoverflowException.

What I have to do?